# Jquery ui call a function only when the object has moved

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

So, let's say i have one simple div:

```
<div class="drag"></div>
```

css i think does not matter in this case, and here is my simple `draggable` function

```
$(".drag").draggable({
  axis: "y"
});
```

Now how can i call a function only when `drag` div actually moves 1px or more?
I have gone trough all events and options, and the closes i got is `drag` event, but the problem is that it keeps executing even if my div stands still, ever 1sec or so...

Comment: `stop:function(event, ui){}` holds the callback method you're looking for. In here, you can test for `ui.position` and make your comparison against a variable you declare outside of the scope of the draggable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var lastPos = 0;
$("#drag").draggable({
  axis: "y",
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    if(Math.abs(ui.position.top - lastPos) >= 1)
    {
      //Moved 1px or more
      alert("Moved "+Math.abs(ui.position.top - lastPos)+" Pixels");
    }
    lastPos = ui.position.top;
  }
});
```

Now just replace the following with your function:

```
alert("Moved "+Math.abs(ui.position.top - lastPos)+" Pixels");
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand me, this will only do something when dragging stops, but i need it to keep doing something while dragging is in action

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do something like this:

```
$(".drag").draggable({
  axis: "y",
  start: function() {
    $(this).data('startPos', $(this).offset());
  },
  drag: function() {
    if ($(this).data('startPos') != $(this).offset()) {
      alert('It moved!');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand me, this will only do something when dragging stops, but i need it to keep doing something while dragging is in action

Comment: Ok, I just changed `stop` to `drag` and it should work how you want now.

Comment: well now we are back where we have started, because it would keep calling alert even if i stop dragging and just stand still